# WooCommerce Bookings - Comparing two timestamps with PHP on custom dates format

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, timestamp

Using [WooCommerce Bookings plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/bookings/), I'm developing a system where I have to compare two dates with PHP.

I have the next sql query to get this date:

```
 $consulta2="SELECT meta_value FROM pwkynbjbwoocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE  meta_key='Fecha de Reserva' AND order_item_id=".$row["order_item_id"];
```

**`Fecha de Reserva`** give us a spanish date like **`septiembre 2016`**, or **`septiembre 1, 2016`** (September 2016, or September 1,2016) for example.

I want to compare one date with "today", so I have tried to use this PHP code:

```
 if (strtotime($row2["meta_value"])>time()){}
```

**But it doesn't work.**

**How can I achieve this?**

Thanks

Comment: Would it not be more beneficial to compare the dates in the SQL side? It would not require the roundtrip and memory for all the rows, only those that are matching your criteria.

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump($row2["meta_value"])`?

Comment: I have this for example: string(12) "febrero 2017" or string(18) "septiembre 1, 2016"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is it possible with this custom function where I list in an associative array the spanish month with numerical month as key, and I reorder the date to output it through strtotime() function. This function can also return the current time with 'now' as parameter.

This is the function code:

```
function bk_date( $date ) {

    // Removing the coma (if there is a coma + a space)
    $my_time = str_replace ( ',', '', $date );
    // or replacing the coma by a space (if there is a coma alone without a space)
    // $my_time = str_replace ( ',', ' ', $the_date );

    $my_time_arr = explode( ' ', $my_time );
    $my_time_count = count( $my_time_arr );
    $month = $my_time_arr[0];
    if ( count( $my_time_arr ) > 2 ) { // When there is the month, the day and the year
        // Formating the day in 2 digits
        $day = $my_time_arr[1] < 10 ? '0'.$my_time_arr[1] : $my_time_arr[1];
        $year = $my_time_arr[2];
    } else { // When there is the month, the day and the year
        $year = $my_time_arr[1];
    }
    // Array of spanish month
    $month_arr = array('01' => 'enero', '02' => 'febrero', '03' => 'marzo', '04' => 'abril', '05' => 'mayo', '06' => 'junio', '07' => 'julio', '08' => 'agosto', '09' => 'septiembre', '10' => 'octubre', '11' => 'noviembre', '12' => 'diciembre');

    // Browse the list of month and compare (when $value match, it's replace by the index $key
    foreach ( $month_arr as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $month == $value ) {
            $month = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( count( $my_time_arr ) > 2 )
        $result = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
    else
        $result = $year . '-' . $month;

    return $date == 'now' ? strtotime( $date ) : strtotime( $result );
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

As I don't really know if the date is like **`septiembre 1, 2016`** or like **`septiembre 1,2016`** (without a space after the coma), you will find a commented alternative in the code above.

My code work also for **`febrero, 2016`** or **`febrero 2016`** date format.

Please check that I haven't make any mistakes in the month names located in **`$month_arr`** array…

---

> **Usage:**

```
echo bk_date($row2["meta_value"]); // display the timestamp of your spanish date.

// Comparing 2 timestamps (bk_date('now') return the "current time").
if ( bk_date($row2["meta_value"]) > bk_date('now') ) {
    // do something
}
```